# How to animate the progress bar in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a slider using jQuery. I had a thumbnail and captions on my photo sliders. There is a progress bar fixed position below the image thumbnail at the middle between the caption and the photo.

The slider can be drag left or right. When the slider remain stationary, the progress bar's width is zero. When users drag the photo toward the left for next photo, the progress bar's width is increasing animately, until the next photo is nearly being replaced on the starting point (progress bar's width nearly 100% then go back to 0% width again).

**Illustration**

```
# Photo
# Progress bar
# Caption
```

**Problem**

> Currently the progress bar is at X width. When I drag slider to the left, the width increase but it didn't work on what I mentioned above.

**Demo**

https://codepen.io/abelchun39/pen/vedBPx

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want to create a smooth transition between the different states/width of the progress bar. Using the css prop `transition:
 <prop-to-be-animated> <duration> <timing-function>` should do the job. E.g. in your case:

```
.bar {
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out; 
}
```

Example on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/zERqmV

Comment: Thanks. But when I drag toward the left side, the progress bar will increase toward full width then come back to zero width again once the slider moved to second photo.

Comment: The JS seems to be a bit quirky. I get different widths for the progress bar when doing the same multiple times :(

Comment: I change my outcome. I want to do something like this. The bar will automatically animate increase until the end of the width of slider, then reset again. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a8DxF/